# Filtered pandas dataframe containing boolean version of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In pandas I have a dataframe with X by Y dimension containing values.

Then I have an identical pandas dataframe with X by Y dimension (same as df1) containing True/False values.

I want to return only the elements from df1 where the same location on df2 the value = True.

What is the fastest way to do this? Is there a way to do this without converting to numpy array?

Comment: It would help if you would [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input and expected output. It might be as simple as `df1[df2]` or it might be more complex, but we don't have enough detail to answer meaningfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having the reproducible example, I may be missing a couple tweaks/details here, but I think you may be able to accomplish this by dataframe multiplication

```
df1.mul(df2)
```

This will multiply each element by the corresponding element in the other dataframe, where `True` will act to return the other element and `False` will return a null.

Comment: Why not just `df1[df2]`?

Comment: Of note: scotscotmcc approach will replace masked values with 0, @not_speshal approach will replace with NaN

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html)

```
df1.mask(df2)
```

This is similar to `df1[df2]` and replaces hidden values with NaN, although you can choose the value to replace with using the `other` option

A quick benchmark on a 10x10 dataframe suggests that the `df.mul` approach is ~5 times faster